# Unity Mesh bad bounds when animated - Exporting models from Blender

Tags: unity-game-engine, blender, 3d-modelling

I am issues importing a character model made in Blender that I want to test in Unity. I wanted to animate it, but something is wrong with the rigging or skinning. When I turn the camera, sometimes the part of the character is not drawn, even when it would be in the view.
[image]
[image]
(I also saw some broken finger bones when exporting and importing .fbx-es. Importing the .blend directly seems to have fixed things mostly.)

After a bit of investigation, it turns out that the bounds for the model are not transformed properly:
[image]
I tried changing the parent bone of this skinned mesh both in Blender and in Unity, but it never seemed to fix the issue properly, as rotations were not applied properly.
As a band-aid fix I merged all skinned meshes in Blender, and it gave me nice big bounds, but it is still badly transformed. The issue is only less noticeable because of the sheer size of it.
[image]
How can I fix this?